# Drupal 7 on search: multiple select box as dropdown with checkboxes (or something)

Tags: search, drupal-7, facet

D7 Install
Relevant Modules: Views, Search API, Solr integration module, Facet search,

I am trying to streamline search functionality to include a keyword search, and a multiple select drop down box. I'm using the faceted search box.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute "**multiple**" with the value **TRUE/FALSE** for enable/disable the multi select options in the drupal drop down select field. If the value TRUE is set to the attribute "multiple", then it enables the multi select option. Please refer the below code for multiselect drop down.

```
$all_users = entity_load('user');
foreach($all_users as $value) {
  $user_list = (array)$value;
  if($user_list['uid'] > 1) {
    $users[$user_list['uid']] = $user_list['name'];
  }
}
$form['accessible_users'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $users,
  '#title' => t('Accessible Users'),
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#description' => t('Slect the users who have rights to access this article.'),
);
```

If you couldn't clear with my answer , please refer the [Drupal api page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#multiple)